# Kohana 3.2 - Database Session losing data on new Page Request

Tags: database, session, redirect, kohana

I've setup my dev Kohana server to use an encrypted database as the default Session type.  I'm also using this in combination with Auth to implement user authentication.

Right now my user's are able to authenticate correctly and the authentication keys are being stored in the session.  I'm also storing additional data like the user's firstname and businessname during the login procedure.

When my login function is ready to redirect the user to the user dashboard, I'm able to see all the data correctly when I do `$session::instance()->as_array();` (`Array ( [auth_user] => NRyk6lA8 [businessname] => Dudetown [firstname] => Matt )`)

As soon as I redirect the user to another page, `$session::instance()->as_array();` is empty.

By dumping out the Session::instance() object, I can see that the Session id's are still the same.

When I look at my database table though, i dont see any session records being saved and my session table is empty.

My bootstrap.php contains:

```
Session::$default = 'database';
Cookie::$salt = 'asdfasdf';
Cookie::$expiration = 1209600;
Cookie::$domain = FALSE;
```

and my session.php config file looks like:

```
return array(
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'auth_user',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 24 * 3600,
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id' => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents' => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,        
    ),
);
```

I've looked high and low for an answer.. if anyone has any suggestions, i'm all ears!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem once. It was allowing me to log in with some browsers (safari and firefox) and it was failing to login with chrome and internet explorer. After working on it so much and debugging I saw the problem was because of setting

```
Cookie::$domain = 'domain.tld';
```

I made it work with correcting it:

```
Cookie::$domain = '.domain.tld';
```

check around.

Comment: Thanks Sinan,

Yes, I actually saw your post in the Kohana forums and implemented the Cookie::$domain = FALSE but unfortunately it didn't work.

I originally tried it with my '.domain.tld' but i wasn't sure if it work working properly because i had my server instance installed in subdirectories and it was still giving me troubles.

I'm going to be deploying to a transitioning server very soon so I'll be able to try out your suggestion shortly.

Thanks for your input and I'll reply to this thread with my findings

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Now that I got my encryption settings sorted out, I was able to get everything working properly with the single session_id thanks to setting the domain properly.  

Everything is working properly... thanks everyone!  This tip helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Session::instance()` with config group parameter. By default parameter is `'default'`, in you case you need to call like this -> `Session::instance('database')`.
Or you can rename

```
return array(
   'database' => array(
     'name' => 'auth_user',
      .....
```

To

```
return array(
   'default' => array(
     'name' => 'auth_user',
      .....
```

**Edit1**: Sorry, I did not paid attention to your bootstrap.php settings... But still make sure that after redirect you call correct session instance.

**Edit2**: Check Session's `write()` [method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Session_Database#write). I think that is what you need :)

Comment: Thanks egis..
Unfortunately this is still acting up.

I even put a `print_r(Session::instance('database')->as_array());` in base controller's before() method and when my user authenticates, it gets populated but as soon as i go to a new page the array is empty.

Comment: Check my answer, "Edit2" part :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you error logs.

If you are using the database session encryption, make sure that you have added a 'key' to the encryption config file.

Comment: Ok so your tip was definitely helpful!  In my workflow I wrote my own Auth driver that connects to my own authentication server that communicates via JSON messages to a custom API..

In my process, i forgot to create my encrypt.php config file which I did and now can successfully write values to my database which is great.  The problem is.. every time I navigate from page to page, it continues to generate new ids.

I'm going to play around with Cookie::$domain parameter some more but I definitely had problems because my encrypt.php file didn't exist

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `Session::instance('type')->get()` you get the whole Session Data.
Were '`type`' is MUST or you get default File type. If you mix both, you get an Session decryption Error.

I think it's always a good Idea to create a siteConfig File with all Settings of you Project.

In case of Session I've done like this:

```
Created a config File config/siteConfig.php
```

with:

```
return array('sessionType' => 'database');
```

Then load that Stuff with:

```
$sessType = Kohana::$config->load('siteConfig')->get('sessionType');
```

Now you have always your Session with:

```
Session::instance($sessType)
```

So done you should never have problems with Sessions